# Send Azure AD B2C Claims That Are Hidden from the User

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm [sending claims to B2C via a JWT](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com_B2C_1A_invitation.xml) following the [WingTig Games demo code](https://wingtipgamesb2c.azurewebsites.net/Invitation/Create).  How do I hide the claims on my self-asserted signup `TechnicalProfile` from the user (LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonNameWithIDs shown below)?

---

I've tried removing the `UserInputType` node from my `ClaimType` definition but then I get the following error in the User Journey Player:

> Output claim type "extension_my_claim" specified in the technical profile with id "LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonNameWithIDs" in policy "B2C_1A_signup_signin_extensions" of tenant "mytenant.onmicrosoft.com" does not specify a UserInputType or a DefaultValue, and is not retrieved from a ValidationTechnicalProfile either.

So then I removed my claims from the `InputClaims` and `OutputClaims` of that `TechnicalProfile` and that removed the error but the values were not persisted then.

---

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonNameWithIDs">
    <DisplayName>User ID signup with associate and org id</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
        <Item Key="LocalAccountType">Username</Item>
        <Item Key="LocalAccountProfile">true</Item>
        <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
    </CryptographicKeys>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_my_claim" /> 
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_my_claim" Required="true"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonName" />
    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Can you update the question to explain which technical profile you are referring to, and by "how do I hide claims", you mean that you do not want to show them on the self-asserted profile?

Comment: Hey @OmerIqbal that this correct, my self-asserted profile.  I've updated the question, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to persist the claim in the directory without showing it to the user, the best option would be:

1. Add it as an `InputClaim` to the `LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonNameWithIDs` technical profile
2. Add it as a `PersistedClaim` in the `AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonName` technical profile, which will write it to the directory

All you are doing is sending the claim in all the way for persistence, but declaring that you do not want an `OutputClaim` from the `SelfAssertedAttributeProvider`.

When you add the claim as an `OutputClaim`, then you are declaring that `SelfAssertedAttributeProvider` needs to have a way to get the value. As of today, it can be sourced from any one of the three possible ways:

1. Provided by the user (which requires `UserInputType` in the `ClaimType` definition)
2. Retrieved from a `ValidationTechnicalProfile`
3. Provided as a `DefaultValue` of the `OutputClaim` in the policy

The error you were getting was likely because there was no way for the `SelfAssertedAttributeProvider` technical profile to get a value for this claim.

Answer (score 1):

As the answer above states

in a self asserted technical profile an output claim presents it to the user

If the claim has been previously populated in a previous step you dont need to pass claims from step to step, they remain in the claim bag until the end of the journey or until you use a transformation to delete them.

Comment: how do we delete claims? I know about NullClaim, but what about Date and Boolean type claims?